# Using Babel + grunt to work with ES6 - how to transform require statements?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to start using ES6, and I want to use grunt to manage my files. This is my project structure so far:

```
Gruntfile.js
package.json
dist/
src/
  index.es6
```

And this is what `index.es6` looks like:

```
import MapGL from 'react-map-gl';
const data = [];
const viewport = new Viewport();
```

These packages are all defined in `package.json` and installed.

How do I turn this ES6 file into ES5 JavaScript? Right I'm able to turn it into JavaScript of a sort, but it's not transforming the `require` statements at all.

This is my current Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ';'
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['src/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
        }
      }
    },
    jshint: {
      files: ['src/index.js', 'test/index.js'],
      options: {
        reporterOutput: '',
        esnext: true,
        globals: {
          console: true,
          module: true,
          document: true
        }
      }
    },
    babel: {
        files: {
            expand: true,
            src: ['src/*.es6'],
            ext: '-compiled.js'
        },
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            presets: ['babel-preset-es2015']
        }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
      tasks: ['babel', 'jshint', 'concat']
    }
  });
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['babel', 'jshint', 'concat', 'uglify']);
};
```

Running `grunt` produces the following files:

```
Gruntfile.js
package.json
dist/
  myproject.js
src/
  index.es6
  index-compiled.js
  index-compiled.map
```

But `myproject.js` contains the line `var _reactMapGl = require('react-map-gl');` which fails in the browser.

Comment: You need to use a transpiler such as `babel` in your grunt pipeline. That will convert (transpile) your code from whatever versions of js you are using into ES5 which is the current standard for browsers.

Comment: https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel

Comment: You'll likely also want to use something such as `Browserify` in your pipeline to handle linking all your imports and such.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst thanks. I am already using babel, see the line `grunt.registerTask('default', ['babel', 'jshint', 'concat', 'uglify'])` in the gruntfile. Do I need browserify as well?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that. Yeah, you'll likely need Browserify as well - at its most basic, it will output a single file composed of all your modules

Answer (score 32):

Yes, as per [@Matthew Herbst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2518231/matthew-herbst) recommendation, [Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) will handle the `import` bindings for the ES6 modules. Also a package named [babelify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babelify) will help to handle your babel browserify transform.

The following seems to work well:

#### Use `babel-cli` instead of `babel`.

1. It's worth noting that [Babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel) has been replaced with [babel-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-cli) as of babel 6 *(see their [blog](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6) for more info on that)*. 
   So, firstly, remove/uninstall it from your `package.json` (if it exists!):

   `$ npm uninstall babel --save-dev`

   ...and uninstall [grunt-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-babel):

   `$ npm uninstall grunt-babel --save-dev`
2. Install [babel-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-cli) and also include the [babel preset for all es2015 plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015):

   `$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015`
3. Next, create a [.babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) file and save it in your projects root directory containing the following code:

```js
    {
        "presets": ["es2015"]
    }
```

#### `grunt-browserify`

4. Next, install [grunt-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-browserify) and save it to your `package.json`:

   `$ npm install grunt-browserify --save-dev`

#### `babelify`

5. Install [babelify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babelify) to handle your babel browserify transform:

   `$ npm install babelify --save-dev`

#### `Gruntfile.js`

6. Next update your `Gruntfile.js` by **deleting** the existing `babel` task:

```js
    // DELETE the following...
    babel: {
        files: {
            expand: true,
            src: ['src/*.es6'],
            ext: '-compiled.js'
        },
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            presets: ['babel-preset-es2015']
        }
    },
```

7. ...and **adding** the following `browserify` task instead:

```js
    browserify: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                // destination for transpiled js : source js
                'dist/myproject.js': 'src/index.es6'
            },
            options: {
                transform: [['babelify', { presets: "es2015" }]],
                browserifyOptions: {
                    debug: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

8. **Registering your grunt tasks:**
   It's likely that you will also need to update and change the order of the tasks in the array passed to `grunt.registerTask`. To this:

```js
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint',
    //'concat', <-- Probably don't need to concat the files, assuming index.es6 imports the necessary modules.
    'browserify:dist',
    'uglify'
]);
```

#### Additional note:

There *may* be some benefits in using [react presets](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) in addition to the [es2015 presets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015) - which would entail modifying points 2, 3, and 7 above accordingly, however, I haven't used it myself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me. If you get errors thrown by jshint runs, add ```"esversion": 6``` to the 'jshint' section of gruntfile.js

Comment: @JoeTidee Yes - good catch! The [esnext](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esnext) option has been deprecated in favour of [esversion](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion).

Comment: Worked like charm.

Comment: This is awesome as we still use grunt and needed to get vue working. One additional thing to note is promises will still not work in environments such as IE11. To fix that, "npm install --save babel-polyfill" and then include this line at the top of your scripts file "import "babel-polyfill";"

Comment: I received the following error following the steps above: "Fatal error: Cannot find module '@babel/core' babelify@10 requires Babel 7.x (the package '@babel/core'). If you'd like to use Babel 6.x ('babel-core'), you should install 'babelify@8'." and was able to fix it by running `npm install @babel/core --save-dev`

Comment: Also the presets in browserify.dist.options.transform had to be specified as an array for me

Comment: The example above did not work for me with various exceptions. It seems like the `babel-preset-es2015` package was deprecated in favor of another package mentioned here: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/env/ Both the grunt config options and the `.babelrc` files has to be updated with the new preset. Also mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889188/cannot-find-module-babel-preset-es2015