# Cannot find module babel-preset-es2015

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

Getting same error again again: `Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015'`.

**Full error log:**

```
ERROR in ./main.js Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015' from 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactApp'
 at Function.module.exports [as sync] (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:43:15)
 at resolveStandardizedName (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:101:31)
 at resolvePreset (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:58:10)
 at loadPreset (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:77:20)
 at createDescriptor (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
 at items.map (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50)
 at Array.map ()
 at createDescriptors (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
 at createPresetDescriptors (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
 at passPerPreset (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:58:96) @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./main.js main[2]
```

Answer (score 118):

For Babel version 6 the package name is `babel-preset-es2015` and for Babel version 7 the package name is `@babel/preset-es2015`.

From the error it seems that you're using version 7. The `es20XX-presets` are deprecated, so I recommend you switch to [`@babel/preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env).

First install the preset (using `npm`):

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
```

Then add the preset to your `.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Comment: I am getting Unexpected token { error while using preset-env

Comment: @Do NHu Vy [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65690420/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-babel-loader-lib-index-js i'm getting quite same error. Can you help me.

Comment: About 2 years I don't program NodeJS, JavaScript, I don't know.

Answer (score 10):

Thing in that the babel 7 uses `@babel/preset-env`. Other presets are deprecated
Here saying about this https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration#yearly-preset-deprecations-blog-2017-12-27-nearing-the-70-releasehtml-deprecated-yearly-presets-eg-babel-preset-es20xx

You should specify in a configuration file (I don't know if you are using Webpack or something else) preset as "@babel/preset-env". Install it through `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env`

For example, you are using Webpack module bundler. In that case, specify like this:

```
use: {
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
                presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
      }
}
```

Here is a documentation https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/ if you suddenly will need.

Happy coding!