# How to fix "Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, npm

So I have been trying to setup React Js environment. I am facing the babel dependencies error. I know this problem is very common and there are tons of answers available but none of them have worked for me so far.
I have searched through the internet to solve it but it still shows the same error.

This is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR in ./main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015' from 'D:\my-app'
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (D:\my-app\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:58:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (D:\my-app\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:101:31)
    at resolvePreset (D:\my-app\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:58:10)
    at loadPreset (D:\my-app\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:77:20)
    at createDescriptor (D:\my-app\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at items.map (D:\my-app\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (D:\my-app\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (D:\my-app\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at passPerPreset (D:\my-app\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:58:96)
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html] 448 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpac
```

This is my .babelrc

```
    {
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/bundle'),
      filename: 'index_bundle.js'
   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   plugins:[
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         template: './index.html'
      })
   ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889188/cannot-find-module-babel-preset-es2015

Answer (score 35, accepted):

babel-loader@8.x uses Babel 7.x, which is @babel/core@^7.0.0, and more importantly in your case @babel/preset-env@7 replaces babel-preset-env@^1.7.0.

You'll need to make sure to do

```
npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

and update your Babel config to use @babel/preset-env instead of babel-preset-env with something like

```
"presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env"
]
```

Note: For others coming across this, the issue may also be that you're using plugins/preset from Babel 6 on Babel 7. This may be hard to notice if you're using a third-party Babel preset since the versions of the presets may not match the version of Babel itself.

Comment: `npm i -D @babel/core @babel/preset-env`

Answer (score 22):

For NPM, run

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

FOR YARN, run

```
yarn add --dev babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, as the NPM version solved my error exactly. for "Failed to compile. Module not found: Can't resolve .../react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js'

Comment: thank you, dont know why but it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Late but might be helpful.

Downgrade the version of @babel-loader to version 7.
It worked for me when i encountered same problem

Answer (score 1):

If you noticed this after installing a package like web3.

Kill the server and try to rebuild hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

**The full code is here**

1. Install

npm i -D webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/node @babel/polyfill @babel/preset-env @babel/register babel-loader babel-register html-webpack-plugin

2. .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

3. webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
    entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/app.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ],
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        devServer: {
            static: {
              directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
            },
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have to delete `./node_modules` and run `yarn install` and then `./bin/webpack` to recompile everything.