# Strapi develop command failed

Tags: reactjs, strapi, babel-loader

I am trying to set up the strapi. I managed to create app succesfully. But when I run the command  **yarn develop** I get following errors

```
Error: ./.cache/plugins/strapi-plugin-content-manager/admin/src/components/RepeatableComponent/Banner.js 2:87
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:87)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

What I have tried so far:

- created new app
- tried solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098779/how-to-fix-module-build-failed-from-node-modules-babel-loader-lib-index-js)
- tried creating app using templates
- tried updating babel
- tried updating all packages

I haven't find anything helpful on Strapi website or github issues

Answer (score 1):

Finally,
I managed to resolve the issue.
You need to update the **webpack.config.js**
from

```
require.resolve('@babel/preset-env')
```

to

```
[require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),{ targets: "defaults" }]
```

inside the module options

Answer (score 0):

You can find here more precise answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68531196/13282460

Quote

"**1. Better solution.**

Check if your Strapi project is nested within another project that uses babel/webpack. I had some old files in my directory with all my projects. When I removed them, it works.

**2. Workaround solution (With every packages update, it will be back to an earlier version)**

1. in your strapi folder, go to → node_modules/strapi-admin/webpack.config.js
2. locate the line → require.resolve('@babel/preset-env')
3. replace it with [require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),{ targets: 'defaults' }],
4. run the command - npm run dev"