# Attempting to run strapi gives module parse error

Tags: node.js, npm, strapi

I'm attempting to run a strapi project via npm on Ubuntu 20.04 with "npm run develop". The code is from a group project of mine, and no one else is encountering these issues.

```
Error: ./.cache/plugins/strapi-plugin-content-manager/admin/src/components/RepeatableComponent/Banner.js 2:87
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:87)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

I've attempted the solutions on these threads:
[Strapi develop command failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856970/strapi-develop-command-failed),
[How to fix "Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098779/how-to-fix-module-build-failed-from-node-modules-babel-loader-lib-index-js)

Neither of which have worked.

I've also attempted:

- Reinstalling Ubuntu
- Reinstalling Babel
- Downgrading or trying different versions of Babel

Here's my project's package.json, which should hopefully provide more context

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.33.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "knex": "0.21.18",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.0",
    "strapi": "3.5.4",
    "strapi-admin": "3.5.4",
    "strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.5.4",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.5.4",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.5.4",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.5.4",
    "strapi-plugin-graphql": "3.5.4",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.5.4",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.5.4",
    "strapi-utils": "3.5.4"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "ab32cbf0-3e4d-42ea-a078-e816435ef1f7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x",
    "npm": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Am I just improperly using my package.json file? Any tips or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Better solution.**

Check if your Strapi project is nested within another project that uses babel/webpack. I had some old files in my directory with all my projects. When I removed them, it works.

**2. Workaround solution** (With every packages update, it will be back to an earlier version)

1. in your strapi folder, go to → `node_modules/strapi-admin/webpack.config.js`
2. locate the line → `require.resolve('@babel/preset-env')`
3. replace it with `[require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),{ targets: 'defaults' }],`
4. run the command - `npm run dev`