# Laravel Mix "npm run dev module build failed, cannot find module ... but all are installed

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, babel-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

What I have:

1. macOS Big Sur
2. node 14 with nvm ( I have also try the 17 )
3. npm 8.1.3
4. Laravel 8

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vuetify": "^2.6.0"
  }
}
```

What I have do:

```
npm i

npm run dev // or npm run watch or npm run production, same error
```

The error ( Module build failed for babel-loader and mini-css-extract-plugin ):

```
ERROR in ../../../../Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/resources/js/app.js
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js'
Require stack:
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js:412:9
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:802:24)
    at NormalModule.build (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:956:15)
    at /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1367:12
    at NormalModule.needBuild (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1243:32)
    at Compilation._buildModule (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1348:10)
    at /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:303:10
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at AsyncQueue._startProcessing (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:293:26)

ERROR in ../../../../Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js'
Require stack:
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js:412:9
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:802:24)
    at NormalModule.build (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:956:15)
    at /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1367:12
    at NormalModule.needBuild (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1243:32)
    at Compilation._buildModule (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1348:10)
    at /Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:303:10
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncQueue._startProcessing (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:293:26)
    at AsyncQueue._ensureProcessing (/Volumes/Websites_#02/websites/dev.crost.it/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:280:12)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:464:21)

webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

What I have try for solve:

```
npm link babel-loader // npm link mini-css-extract-plugin
rm -rf node_module && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install
```

Same error in all projects, i have also try:

1. install modules globally with -g option, nothing change
2. Remove nvm npm and reinstall with homebrew

Comment: Please, try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098779/how-to-fix-module-build-failed-from-node-modules-babel-loader-lib-index-js

Comment: Thnak's but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack`?

I found this answear here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62933979/14807111

Comment: Thank's but nothing change ...

Comment: I am not sure, but you can have a "wrong" nodejs version for that package. try to downgrade.