# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to create a build file for my React application using the webpack command, but I am encountering a module error. The traceback for this error is provided below. I am using the simple-walletconnect package in my app. Can you help me understand the cause of this error and how I can resolve it?

```
 ERROR in ./frontend/src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-core'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\index.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
- If you want to resolve "@babel/core", use "module:@babel/core"
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at resolve (C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:164:23)
    at resolveStandardizedName (C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:100:7)
    at resolvePreset (C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:48:10)
    at loadPreset (C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:67:20)
    at createDescriptor (C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (C:\Users\AHMED\Dotesrow\dotescrow\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)

webpack 5.13.0 compiled with 1 error in 1736 ms
```

**babelrc**

```
     {
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react","@babel/core"],
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dotescrow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./frontend/static/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./frontend/static/main.js/main.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/AhmedYasin487/Dotescrow.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/AhmedYasin487/Dotescrow/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/AhmedYasin487/Dotescrow#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^5.13.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@walletconnect/client": "^1.3.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.4",
    "walletconnect": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

**webpack.confi.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/static/main.js'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  mode:'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        // include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        
      }
    ]
  },

}
```

Visual error.

[image]

If more code is required then tell me in the comments. I'll update my question with that information thank you.

Comment: Why are you putting `@walletconnect/client` as a Babel preset? As the error says, a preset with that name does not exist.

Comment: @loganfsmyth i updated my babelrc file by removing **@walletconnect/client** . I also updated my babelrc in this question and updated the new traceback. And i guess i'm getting same traceback after removing walletconnect package from babelrc file

Comment: You have it in your Webpack config too.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I removed that and finally that error remove but got another quite same error **Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-core'** . I also updated my question and add complete traceback .

Comment: Remove `"@babel/core"` from your presets too.

Comment: @loganfsmyth It removed error and created build and after running the server. I'm getting again that walletconnect module error. you Can see in the picture which i just added in the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

`@babel/core` is not a preset, remove that from the `presets` array in your babelrc.

Comment: It removed error and created build and after running the server. I'm getting again that walletconnect module error. you Can see in the picture which i just added in the end of the question.

Comment: That error is indicating that you still have the `walletconnect` module in your babelrc.

Comment: but you can see i just removed that then why ?

Comment: Did you kill and restart webpack after removing it?