# How to fix webpack dependency errors

Tags: node.js, webpack, dependencies

I've been trying to upgrade node version and have got in a bit of a state. I've tried removing node_modules and reinstalling, updating etc many times. What is going on here?

```
ERROR in ./src/app/index.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL]: Cannot find module '../lib/statuses'
Require stack:
- /var/app/node_modules/caniuse-lite/dist/unpacker/feature.js
- /var/app/node_modules/browserslist/node.js
- /var/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js
- /var/app/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/index.js
- /var/app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/debug.js
- /var/app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js
- /var/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /var/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /var/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /var/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /var/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
- /home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js
- /home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js (While processing: /var/app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/node_modules/caniuse-lite/dist/unpacker/feature.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)

webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 1 error in 15668 ms
```

edit - seems that's not my only problem :( Not sure if related:

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/library/fn/object/get-prototype-of'
 Require stack:
 - /var/app/node_modules/babel-runtime/core-js/object/get-prototype-of.js
 - /var/app/node_modules/fb/lib/index.js
 - /var/app/src/controllers/app.js
 - /var/app/src/index.js
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:61:29)
     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/node_modules/babel-runtime/core-js/object/get-prototype-of.js:1:31)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/home/app_admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39) {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: [
     '/var/app/node_modules/babel-runtime/core-js/object/get-prototype-of.js',
     '/var/app/node_modules/fb/lib/index.js',
     '/var/app/src/controllers/app.js',
     '/var/app/src/index.js'
   ]
```

Not entirely sure what else to add - these are the errors im getting

Comment: When you delete **node_modules** and try complete uninstall, also delete **package-lock.json**

Comment: Tried that. Then it says aws-sdk isn't found (it is there though, and in package.json. So I install that. Then 'sharp' image tool starts playing up. so I fix that. Then node-libcurl...

Comment: There might be some sort of conflict/interference with global installations. E.g. you have webpack installed globally, and also a dependency in your own package.json

Comment: Any idea what I should do? I've tried removing globally and locally, then installing just locally, or just globally. Even tried a npm install statuses to see if that helped! Nothing seems to fix the need for ../lib/statuses

Comment: Does the **/var/app/node_modules/caniuse-lite/dist/lib** folder exist and is there a file named **statuses.js** in it?

Comment: No, it didn't so installed it. That errors been replaced by errors about babel-loader-es2015 now (saying it's not supposed to export). Which I've tried installing and reinstalling. Can't find any references to it in .babelrc or webpack config. God I hate webpack!

Comment: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /var/app/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/lib/index.js

Comment: Maybe you should post your whole **package.json**.

Comment: Thanks @tromgy - it's sorted now - I'll update an answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's what I did in the end which seemed to fix it:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev webpack webpack-cli
npm install --save caniuse-lite
npm install -g webpack@latest webpack-cli@latest
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react webpack
```

Then additionally, edited `.babelrc` to remove the old es2015 preset and end up with:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {}]]
}
```

Thanks to @tromgy for assistance and this link also:
[Cannot find module babel-preset-es2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889188/cannot-find-module-babel-preset-es2015)