# How to use ES6 import and react in a sailsjs app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, gruntjs, sails.js

I am  trying to update a web app to se the lastest sailsjs and react versions.  The app was already using sails v0.12 an react v0.14.x and ES5 style requirejs.config imports like so:

```
requirejs.config({
  urlArgs: "v=" + myapp.buildNumber,
  paths: {
    'react': '/bower_components/react/react-with-addons',
    'reactdom': '/bower_components/react/react-dom',
    'label': '/js/shared/reactLabel',      
    'moment': '/bower_components/moment/moment',   

  },
  shim: {    
    'reactRedux': ["react"]
  }
    });


require(['react', 'label', 'moment', 'reactdom', ], 
    function (React, Label, moment, ReactDOM, ) {
```

...

Now after updating a ton of npm packages and sails to the latest versions I am trying to get react going on one simple component like so in PCycle.jsx:

```
import React , {Component } from 'react'


class PCycle extends Component {

  render(){
    console.log(this.props);  

    return (
        <div className="post card" >hi world</div>
    )
  }
};
```

But when I load the page that component is on I get this error and the component does not render.

```
VM3398 require.js:165 Uncaught Error: Module name "react" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (VM80 require.js:165)
    at Object.localRequire [as require] (VM80 require.js:1429)
    at requirejs (VM80 require.js:1791)
    at VM1011 pCycle.js:3
```

Other pages in my app that still use the older react version and require syntax still work so maybe I can use that require  syntax on this component too but I would rather be able to do things with import.
  I am new to react and babel so I'm not sure if I need some babel magic or what is going on here.  Should I post my various config json files?  The project like I said is not a  new one created with the react cli.

PS:
I have this babel.js file in my /tasks/config folder:

```
/**
 * Compile JSX files to JavaScript.
 *
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Compiles jsx files from `assest/js` into Javascript and places them into
 * `.tmp/public/js` directory.
 *
 */
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.config.set('babel', {
    dev: {
      options: {
        presets: ["@babel/preset-env",'@babel/react']
      },
      files: [
        {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'assets/js/',
        src: ['**/*.jsx'],
        dest: '.tmp/public/js/',
        ext: '.js'
        },
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'assets/bower_components/react-notification-system',
          src: ['**/*.jsx'],
          dest: '.tmp/public/bower_components/react-notification-system',
          ext: '.js'
        }
      ]
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');
};
```

Maybe those bower_component react-notification-system is somehow messing things up but there is no such folder under assets/bower_components.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with sailsjs, but if it runs in node, then you will need something to transpile the es6 imports, since node does not support them fully yet.

You could use babel to do this like so:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env
```

Then create a .babelrc file in your root to configure and add this:

```
{"presets": ["env"]}
```

If you want to bundle files for serving to the client, you can use a bundler like webpack or parcel.

Comment: Thanks,   I'm sure you are on the right track but I installed some babel stuff already though I'm not sure about that cli.   FYI  I updated my post with my babel.js config file above.  I haven't started bundling anything yet.  I should also mention that we are using Grunt.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested and now when I try to run the app I get this error message: 

error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
error:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aborted due to warnings.
Running "babel:dev" (babel) task
Warning: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. I have not used gulp or grunt with es6 imports before so maybe take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067220/using-babel-grunt-to-work-with-es6-how-to-transform-require-statements